# what is difference making full class static and making functions of the class as static

Tags: c#

Hello All:
what is difference making full class static and making functions of the class as static?
I mean are there any performance issues?

Comment: No performance issues -- a static class is just an abstract sealed class with no instance members or constructors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The feature of static classes was only introduced in C# 2. The CLR doesn't really have such a concept. A static class in C#:

- Has *no* constructors, not even a default parameterless one
- Is sealed: it can't be subclassed
- Is abstract: you can't create instances of it (which also follows from there being no constructors)
- Can only contain static members
- Can't be used as a parameter or variable type or a generic type argument etc.
- Can't specify any base type other than `object`

There's no performance difference between using static members of a "normal" class and using ones in a static class. It's primarily a way of stating the intention that there should never be any instances of this class, without having to provide a private and never-called constructor, and forcing the compiler to check that you're not *trying* to use it as a normal class.

Note that [*extension methods*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) (introduced in C# 3) can only be declared in a top-level, non-generic static class.

Comment: Also: a static class can only inherit from `object`.

Comment: @leppie: I've got the first already, as my second bullet. Will add the bit about having to be a direct subclass of object.

Comment: I noted that, just after I pressed enter :)

Comment: So, Can I have a class (with static methods) which inherits from a class to share some come methods from instead of having a full static class with static methods without any issues?

Answer (score 1):

It has two implications:

1. All methods of the class must also be static.
2. You can't make an instance of that class other places in your code.